# Passing an array stdClass Object from custom module to template

Tags: 8, theming

I’ve created some D8 custom modules which call rest API and and it’s working fine when I get simple array in my `$response`.

In my controller, this is working :

```
return [
            '#theme' => 'webservices_client',
            '#id' => $infos_clients->body->id,
            '#nom' => $infos_clients->body->nom,
 ];
```

But when I receive that kind of array `$response->body` :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [numero] => 625
            [dateDebut] => 2018-09-27T09:21:54.5746973
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [numero] => 468
            [dateDebut] => 2018-05-17T16:50:33.6357383
        )

)
```

I don’t how to send my array from the controller to the twig template and assign variable in `my-module.module`

Could you explain how to this ?

I've tried this kind of thing :

in controller :

```
return [
            '#theme' => 'webservices_informations',
            '#myvariable' => $response,
       ];
```

in my-module.module :

```
function webservices_informations_theme(array $existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return array(
        'webservices_informations' => array(
            'variables' => array(
                'myvariable' => NULL,
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

In twig template :

```
{% for key, value in myvariable %}
            Key : {{ key }}<br>
            Name : {{ value.id }}<br>
{% endfor %
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it was not working because after I've done a simple

```
<pre>
    {{ dump(myvariable) }}
</pre>
```

In order to check if the array was passed to the twig template, everything is working.

So the solution is in `my-template.html.twig`

```
{% for key, value in myvariable %}
    Key : {{ key }}<br>
    Date: {{ value.dateDebut }}<br>
    Societe : {{ value.societe }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```